# Is there an option for gcc which discards -g flag?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gcc

I'm building a package which provides many makefiles, each makefile has hard coded in side something like

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall ...
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall ...
```

I want to discard `-g` option but I don't want to edit all makefiles (even not automatically with `sed` or something similar). The `configure` script which comes with the package doesn't have enable/disable debug option but I can pass it `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` variables and it concatenates their values to the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` variables respectively which include the `-g` option.

Is there an option which will discard `-g` in case it is specified? Something like

```
gcc -option-im-looking-for -g file.c -o file
```

Will build the binary `file` without debug symbols. I don't want to strip the binary, I want it to be created stripped.

Comment: Hmmm You could write a script which called mygcc which parse the received arguments, strips unwanted params, and call gcc. Then use mygcc as compiler. I'm not proud of this answer ^^

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could *negate* the effect of `-g` by adding `-g0`.  Saying

```
gcc -g -g0 foo.c -o file.o
```

would produce a binary identical to one obtained by saying

```
gcc foo.c -o foo.o
```

Quoting `man gcc`:

```
   -glevel
   ...
        Level 0 produces no debug information at all.  Thus, -g0 negates
       -g.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit makefiles. Just override the variables on the command line:

```
$ cat Makefile 
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
all:
    echo $(CFLAGS)
$ make
echo -g -Wall
-g -Wall
$ make CFLAGS=-Wall
echo -Wall
-Wall
```

Comment: But CFLAGS is a very long line (about 100 options, includes etc`), I'm not suppose to know what CFLAGS should be. All I know is what I don't like about it but I can't understand how to fix it.